# Connect to API endpoint from Django and returning data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django form which at the moment checks for postcodes in areas that the app can deliver. I would like to integrate it with postcodes.io API endpoint to check that the actual postcode is valid.

The endpoint is as below:

```
api.postcodes.io/postcodes/:postcode/validate
```

This is my form code:

```
from django import forms

class PostCodeForm (forms.Form):
    pcode = forms.CharField()

    def clean_pcode(self):
        permitted = {'gu15','GF34','FG34','BT25'}
        pcode = self.cleaned_data['pcode'].lower()
        if not pcode[:4] in (permitted):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Apologies, but does not currently deliver to you postcode.")
        return pcode
```

I am stuck in terms of how to integrate with the API endpoint from Django. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with awesome python package [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

```
import requests

def clean_pcode(self):
    pcode = self.cleaned_data['pcode'].lower()
    url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}/validate'.format(pcode)
    r = requests.get(url)
    is_correct = r.json()['result']
    if not is_correct:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Apologies, but does not currently deliver to you postcode.")
    return pcode
```

Of course this is very basic, you should also check reponse code and handle errors.

Comment: Thanks for this. Running it on django this isn't returning the Validation error. I checked it on the python console inserting some value for pcode and it works on the shell. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - code was not indented. This is now working! Thanks. One quick follow up; is_correct holds value "True" or "False". How can 'if not' True or False raise the validation error? If I enter an invalid postcode, is_correct will equal to False...

Comment: Well, if `is_correct` will be equal `False`, then code in `if not is_correct` will be executed and will raise validation error. I am not sure, if that's what you mean. You can always check in the console.